# Having trouble counting in c#

Tags: c#

I am having trouble with this. How can I count a length I want input to.
Lets say I ask a user an input. He enters 10. It counts 1,2,3,4,etc... 10.
Or if users enter 5, 1,2,3,4,5 is output
Thanks.

EDIT:
I am sorry. This isn't homework. School doesn't start till next week and I am practicing.
Sorry, I should have given code.

This is what I had that does work

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter Length");
int length = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

I am just assuming since I am new that I did some sloppy code and am looking for maybe something cleaner. Or another point of view for it.

Comment: What kind of trouble are you having? Can we see some code?

Comment: My code still cuts me short 1

Comment: I'm still not sure what your actual problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update your code with `<=`

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter Length");
int length = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
for (int i = 0; i <= length; i++) 
{ 
  Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Comment: i <= length. Why does this make such a difference

Comment: you are checking till length less than i, that is why its showing one less

Comment: duh! I just got home from working 10 hours. I am going to bed. Thanks!!

Comment: I gave you best answer, again, my brain is fried I am going to bed.

Answer (score 0):

```
        string length;

        Console.Write("Enter Length: ");

        length= Console.ReadLine();

        for (int i = 1; i <= Int32.Parse(length); i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Before I hit refresh I figured this out. Why does i <= length make such a difference

Comment: @AndrewHeid : your code is correct, but because you set i starter value 0, so the result is from 0 to n-1 (totally n number).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the '<' operator to '<=':

```
for (int i = 0; i <= length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```